# Migrate SQL Server CE to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-ce-4, orchardcms-1.9, webmatrix-3

I have finished my first complete Orchard CMS website, developed locally in SQL Server CE. I want to publish it to Azure, but I am having difficulty with the WebMatrix Migrate function.

I have a SQL Server instance in Azure with an blank Orchard database already there (I want to use the replace option late in the migration to just nuke the existing db). I have added my IP to the server firewall rule.

In WebMatrix 3 I can connect to my Azure database using:

- Server: myserver.database.windows.net
- Database: orchard-db
- Username: admin@myserver
- Password: mypassword

I can view the tables in WebMatrix.

When I select my CE sdf file (Orchard.sdf) and click the Migrate button and enter the exact same details I get the following (can provide full stack trace if needed):

> We were unable to connect using the connection details provided.
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException:
>   Failed to connect to server . ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

I'm really not sure what the issue is. I have tried various configurations of the details but nothing seems to work. If I connect as my database user (i.e. not a server admin) I get a different error:

> The server principal "orchard_user" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context.

I went and had something to eat, and now I can get to the next step of the migration. When I select replace database I get the following error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException: Failed to connect to server . ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'admin'.

EDIT: I have come to the conclusion WebMatrix is not going to migrate my SQL Server CE database to my Azure SQL Server database. I installed SQL Server Express and migrated it to that, when I get home from work I will use the SQL Server Migration Assistant to move it to Azure.

Comment: did you not specify a port in your connection string?

Comment: SO seems to have removed my line breaks. You don't seem to input a connection string, only server, db, username and password fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing SQL Server Express, using WebMatrix to migrate the SQL Server CE database to that. I then ran the Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure Database Wizard in SSMS to push my database to Azure.

I can't be certain, but it seems that WebMatrix can't migrate CE to Azure. According to Azure doco:

> It is recommended that you always use the latest version of Management Studio to remain synchronized with updates to Microsoft Azure and SQL Database. Update SQL Server Management Studio.

I guess WebMatrix is behind or something. Hopefully this helps someone in my situation.